# ssis expression file path

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

SSIS expression is written for the Flatfile location.Th is a variable and the value is hardcoded.
Example
@varFileLoc

```
"\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\" +  @[User::varDFolder]
```

this variable value has been passed to a a FEL.When tried in debiugg mode I can see the value of the variable is

```
\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\
```

instead of

```
\\server\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\
```

what might be the reason for this

Comment: They are identical. The debuger shows the string value with special characters escaped

Comment: so this is not an error or refreshing problem!?

Comment: That's normal debuger behaviour, in fact, it would be pretty bad if the debuger behaved in a different way. Imagine what would happen if you saw a string with a large space in it. Is it a tab (`\t`) or four spaces? How would newlines appear? Would extra lines just vanish until you clicked on `...` ?